# Prove that $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\mathbb E[|X_s|^2]<\infty $ where $dX_s=\mu(X_s,s)ds+\sigma (X_s,s)dW_s$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

Let $$|\mu(x,t)|+|\sigma (x,t)|\leq K(1+|x|),$$
for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and some $K>0$. Let $$\begin{cases}d X_t=\mu(X_t,t)\,\mathrm d t+\sigma (X_t,t)d W_t\\X_0=x_0\in\mathbb R\end{cases}.$$

I would like to prove that $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\mathbb E(|X_s|^2)<\infty $

Using Itô formulae gives $$X_t^2=x_0^2+2\int_0^tX_s\mu(X_s,s) d s+\underbrace{\int_0^t \sigma (X_s,s)d W_s}_{=:M_t}+\int_0^t\sigma (X_s,s)^2 d s.$$
Let $\tau_n\nearrow \infty $ s.t. $(M_{\tau_n\wedge t})$ is a martingale. Then $$\mathbb E[X_t^2]\leq x_0^2+2\mathbb E\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_n} X_s\mu(X_s,s) d s+2\mathbb E\int_0^{t\wedge \tau_n}(1+X_s^2)\,\mathrm d s.$$

**Q1)** How can I conclude ?

---

Moreover, I have to deduce that $\mathbb E(|X_t|^2)\leq Ce^{Dt}$ for some $C,D>0$. So, I could easily prove that $$\mathbb E(|X_t|^2)\leq C+D\int_0^t\mathbb E(|X_s|^2)ds,$$
for some $C,D>0$, and thus the result follows from Gronwall's inequality.

**Q2)** Nevertheless, I wonder why $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\mathbb E(|X_s|^2)<\infty $ is required here ?

**Q3)** Moreover, in my Gronwall inequality, continuity of $s\mapsto \mathbb E(|X_s|^2)$ is continuous, and I failed to prove it. Does the continuity of $s\mapsto \mathbb E(|X_s|^2)$ comes from $\sup_{0\leq s\leq t}\mathbb E(|X_s|^2)<\infty $ ?

Comment: Regarding your Q2 and Q3: grönwalls lemma holds for bounded, measurable integrands so if you show boundedness you do not need continuity

Comment: I am sure that you are basing your argument based on an argument for a similar question. Which textbook/lecture notes/video are you using to study SDEs?

Comment: "thus the result follows from Gronwall's inequality." No, since you didn't prove that the rhs is finite. So you should establish something like
$$
\mathbb E(|X_t|^2 1_{\tau_n<t})\leq C+D\int_0^t\mathbb E(|X_s|^2 1_{\tau_n<s})ds
$$
with some suitable $\tau_n$ and then appeal to the Gronwall and Fatou lemmata. 

Concerning the sup, the Gronwall lemma will provide that too. If it were under the expectation sign, this would be a different story.